# Goldbach's conjecture and number of ways in which an even number can be expressed as a sum of two primes

Tags: number-theory

Is there a functon that counts the number of ways in which an even number can be expressed as a sum of two primes?

Comment: there is one, you just defined it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Goldbach's comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_comet) at Wikipedia.

EDIT: To expand on this a little, let $g(n)$ be the number of ways of expressing the even number $n$ as a sum of two primes. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) gives a heuristic argument for $g(n)$ to be approximately $2n/(\log n)^2$ for large $n$. Then it points out a flaw with the heuristic, and explains how Hardy and Littlewood repaired the flaw to come up with a better conjecture. The better conjecture states that, for large $n$, $g(n)$ is approximately $cn/(\log n)^2$, where $c>0$ depends on the primes dividing $n$. In all cases, $c>1.32$.

I stress that this is all conjectural, as no one has been able to prove even that $g(n)>0$ for all even $n\ge4$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such a function and it has been studied for at least a century. See [Sloane's A002375](https://oeis.org/A002375). But it doesn't have a set letter specified for it. Here I will use $g$. So, for example, $g(36) = 4$, $g(38) = 2$. (If you're looking in Sloane's, be sure to divide by 2 before looking up). There is also a function which requires the primes to be distinct, so $31 + 7 = 38$ counts but $19 + 19$ does not; that has also been studied for at least a century.

Now, is there a formula that you can plug in an even number $2n$ and have it give you an answer without knowing the primes up to $n$? I think that if the Riemann hypothesis is proven, it could lead to such a formula. As a quick and dirty estimate, I suggest $g(2n) \approx \frac{n}{8}$; your mileage may vary.

**EDIT:** Gerry Myerson rightly pointed out that $g(2n) < \pi(n)$, and that my quick and dirty estimate is quite inadequate for large numbers. From his comment, I revise my quick and dirty estimate to $g(2n) \approx \frac{n}{4 \log n}$. The point that I was getting at is that Bertrand's postulate tells us there is always at least one prime between $n$ and $2n$, and it seems unlikely to me that each and every prime in that interval would fail to "match" to a prime between 1 and $n$.

Comment: Your $g(n)$ is clearly no bigger than the number of primes up to $2n$. For $n$ large, the number of primes less than $2n$ is roughly $2n/\log n$, which is much smaller than $n/8$. So the "quick and dirty" estimate can't be much good, once $n$ is large enough. Also, to the best of my knowledge, the Riemann Hypothesis has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Mostly good points. As for the Riemann hypothesis, that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem tells us much more than Bertrand's Postulate; instead of one prime between $n$ and $2n$, there are asymptotically $n/\log n$ of them. And a careful consideration of the likelihood of matchups with primes between $1$ and $n$ leads to an estimate of $cn/(\log n)^2$ for $g(n)$, for a certain constant $c$. Have a look at the Wikipedia essay on the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I'm at that delicate halfway point between mathematical ignorance and expertise that makes me very susceptible to information poisoning from Wikipedia.

Comment: You guys, you're basically in agreement on the essential point here: as $n$ gets larger, so does the number of potential Goldbach sums. A quick and dirty estimate is just that, and not a tight upper or lower bound. But Gerry, I think you'd do well to post your own answer. Another way of saying the same thing is that a Goldbach failure number is probably less likely to exist than an odd perfect number.

Comment: @Lisa, I *did* post an answer, over two years ago.

Comment: Wikipedia has an argument in support of the $cn/(\log n)^2$ estimate, and it also has links to the literature, Robert, so poisoning shouldn't be a problem, and taking my word for it shouldn't be a necessity. The truth is out there, for those who go in search of it.

Comment: Maybe this is an opportunity for you to make your answer a little more substantial than just "see Wikipedia," maybe give a $c$ that works reasonably good for, say, up to about $10^{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define g(n) as the number of decompositions of $2n$ into ordered sums of two odd primes ([A002372](https://oeis.org/A002372))

The following sum gives the exact value for g(n):
$$g(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{\pi(2n)} \pi(2n-p(i))-\pi(2n-1-p(i))$$

where $p(n)$ is the nth prime and $\pi(n)$ is the prime-counting function.
Now if you are looking for something that will work without knowing the primes up to $n$, we can get a pretty good estimate from the sum above. Let's consider the sum of all $g(i)$ from $i=3\to n$:
$$ \sum_{i=3}^{n} g(i)$$
From the first sum, we can get:
$$\sum_{i=3}^{n} g(i) = 1+\sum_{i=3}^{\pi(2n)} \pi(2n-p(i))$$
If we replace $\pi(n)$ with $\frac{n}{ln(n)}$ and $p(n)$ with $nln(n)$, we know from the prime number theorem that the bigger the interval $n-3$ gets, the more precise our estimation gets:
$$\sum_{i=3}^{n} g(i) \approx  1+\sum_{i=3}^{\frac{2n}{ln(2n)}} \frac{2n-iln(i)}{ln(2n-iln(i))}$$
Since:
$$ g(n) = \sum_{i=3}^{n} g(i) - \sum_{i=3}^{n-1} g(i)$$
$$ g(n) \approx  (1+\sum_{i=3}^{\frac{2n}{ln(2n)}} \frac{2n-iln(i)}{ln(2n-iln(i))})-(1+\sum_{i=3}^{\frac{2(n-1)}{ln(2(n-1))}} \frac{2(n-1)-iln(i)}{ln(2(n-1)-iln(i))})$$
$$ g(n) \approx  \sum_{i=3}^{\frac{2n}{ln(2n)}} \frac{2n-iln(i)}{ln(2n-iln(i))}-\sum_{i=3}^{\frac{2n-2}{ln(2n-2)}} \frac{2n-2-iln(i)}{ln(2n-2-iln(i))}$$

The results is quite surprising, yet not very practical. The value of the estimation seems to behave like the real g(n), only in a more regular way:
[image]
[image]